# Unable to Execute Tesseract command from python

Tags: python, pycharm, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to execute "tesseract abc.tif abc.txt" from python code as

```
subprocess.call(["tesseract abc.tif abc.txt"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but its showing **'"tesseract abc.tif abc.txt"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

```
subprocess.call(["tesseract"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It is executing the above command without any errors.
***'tesseract abc.tif abc.txt'*** I am able to execute from command prompt externally. Only that command unable to execute from python.I am using PYCHARM IDE

Comment: have you tried to use ``subprocess.call("tesseract abc.tif abc.txt".slit(), shell=False, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you need to use:

```
subprocess.call(["tesseract", "abc.tif", "abc.txt"])
```

Or, you can use simply:

```
import os
os.system("tesseract abc.tif abc.txt")
```

Comment: with ``shell=True`` you must use a string, otherwise it calls only the first element of the list. The above syntax for the first argument should be used with ``shell=False``